# Can I boot from an old harddrive?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, adapter

I have an old computer with [this](https://www.cnet.com/products/fujitsu-mobile-mhk2050at-hard-drive-5-gb-ata-66/) hard-drive with windows me installed. I was wondering if you can boot from it over USB like you can with other new hard-drives with a [SATA adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HJZJI84) for nostalgia's sake?

EDIT: **I'm pretty sure the adapter would have to be a male 22pins (44 pins total) and double sided, with no break in the middle and plated contacts on the top and bottom**

Comment: 1) That should be a standard 40 pin 2.5" IDE connector.  If the drive has some extra pins they are probably for selecting master/slave operation with a jumper.  You shouldn't need to mess with those pins.  2) Will it boot or will it run are two different things.  If you want to use it on a computer with current technology, there's a good chance that you will have trouble finding all of the needed drivers.  It's a good bet that the drivers on the HDD won't include everything you need.

Comment: BTW, if the connector looks like something other than two rows of pins, e.g., a circuit board with foil contacts top and bottom, which it sounds like you may be describing, you may be looking at an interface from the old computer that plugged into the drive's connector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could try it with an IDE-USB 2.5" disk enclosure box, or a alike separate adapter.

If your machine recognizes the disk in BIOS, then it will be up to regular boot procedure prerequisites.  Good luck!